# how to creat list compersion with 2 IFs with 3 expersions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was struggling with syntax to convert the below code to list comprehension but no luck,

```
x = ['3', '15', '161', '2', '4113', '26', '1141', '00', '05', '02', '064']
c = []
for i in x:
   if len(i) <= 2:
      i = '00' + i
   if len(i) <= 3:
      i = '0' + i
   c.append(i)
```

how to place the second condition:

```
['00' + i for i in x if len(i) <= 2 if len(i) <= 3]
```

Comment: Keep it readable the way it is? Note that if what you want to do is pad your string, there are more direct ways to do so, like `out = [n.zfill(3) for n in x]`

Comment: If you are trying to add leading zeroes to get to standard length strings in the list then look up the `zfill` method

Comment: Please fix typos in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never not appending a value to your new list, so you don't need *filters* on your list comprehension. You're just changing *what* you're appending.

```py
[f'000{d}' if len(d) == 1 else \
  f'00{d}' if len(d) == 2 else \
   f'0{d}' if len(d) == 3 else \
         d 
 for d in x]
# ['0003', '0015', '0161', '0002', '4113', '0026', 
#  '1141', '0000', '0005', '0002', '0064']
```

But you can simply use a format specifier in an f-string to accomplish the same.

```py
[f'{int(d):04}' for d in x]
# ['0003', '0015', '0161', '0002', '4113', '0026', 
#  '1141', '0000', '0005', '0002', '0064']
```

Or without the intermediate conversion to an int.

```py
[f'{d:>04}' for d in x]
# ['0003', '0015', '0161', '0002', '4113', '0026', 
#  '1141', '0000', '0005', '0002', '0064']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `base` string and fill the base string base on the length of each item.

```
base = '0000'
res = [base[len(i):] + i for i in x]

# Or by thanks @Chris
# res = [f"{'0' * (4-len(i))}{i}" for i in x]
print(res)
```

---

```
['0003', '0015', '0161', '0002', '4113', '0026', '1141', '0000', '0005', '0002', '0064']
```

Comment: Also: `[f"{'0' * (4-len(i))}{i}" for i in x]`. But really, just use format specifiers. :)

Comment: If you really want to be wild: `[f"{'0' * buf_width}{i}" for i in x for buf_width in [4-len(i)]]`

Answer (score 1):

you can Multiplication operator `*`. Multiplication operator is used with strings in Python for the purpose of repetition.

```
for i in x:
    indx = x.index(i)
    x[indx] = '0'* (4-len(i)) + i
```

using list comprehension,

```
c= [ '0'* (4-len(i)) + i  for i in x]
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

we can give some more flexibility for the numbers to pad with zeros, if we calculate the element with the most digits / characters. so if the longest element will be '4113991', the numbers will all be padded to this length:

```
x = ['3', '15', '161', '2', '4113991', '26', '1141', '00', '05', '02', '064']
len_ = len(max(x,key=len))
print([f"{int(num):0{len_}}" for num in x])
```

output: `['0000003', '0000015', '0000161', '0000002', '4113991', '0000026', ...]`

Comment: Suggestion: `len_ = max(map(len, x))`